# Unable to determine Outlook Item Type in Folder

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am attempting to walk through Outlook folders and save the items (`SaveAs`) therein based on certain criteria (*age, subject, contents*) provided by the user.  The problem that I'm running into is that I am unable to determine what type certain items are within the folder.  I'm using the

```cs
if( currentItem is MailItem )
  // do something
else if (currentItem is AppointmentItem)
  // do something else
// etc.
```

to attempt to determine type and handle that item as appropriate.  Unfortunately, I'm finding several types that don't seem to match any of the listed types that I've tested against.  Using **OutlookSpy** I can view the objects in question which shows as **type 53** `OlObjectClass.olMeetingRequest`.  This doesn't match with either `MeetingItem` or `AppointmentItem` and I don't seem to see any other type listed that would appear to be likely.  There is no `MeetingRequestItem` or equivalent I can find.  The obvious methods such as the `GetType` only says its a COM object and no other methods I've found so far seem to do the trick.

I've read through VSTO for Office 2007 and it didn't provide any guidance that I was able to find either.  I've searched MSDN, this site an numerous others without much luck.  There was a question posted by another user that was similar, but it didn't have any answers.  VS2010 is able to figure it out as you can add a dynamic cast to the Watch List and it displays the object information, it just doesn't tell you what it is.

Sorry for asking what seems to me to be a noob sort of question, but I have tried to figure out an *object to Interop type mapping*.  If anyone has a method for determining Outlook object type dynamically, this would really help; I just haven't had much luck with this...

Answer (score 0):

A meeting request, response, or update is sent as a [`Outlook.MeetingItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.meetingitem.aspx). You can access the underlying [`AppointmentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem.aspx) by using [`MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._meetingitem.getassociatedappointment.aspx).

Here is an [example sourced from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184658.aspx) on how to access an `AppointmentItem` from a `MeetingItem`:

```
Outlook.Folder folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
string filter = "[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request'";
Outlook.Items items = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);
foreach (Outlook.MeetingItem request in items)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt =  request.GetAssociatedAppointment(false);
    if (appt != null)   
        Debug.WriteLine(appt.Subject);
}
```

Comment: @gt2847c If this works for you - please mark it as an answer so others may benefit.